# Can clang-format align a block of #defines for me?

Tags: c++, c, clang-format

I have a source file containing some lines like this;

```
#define ARC_V2_LP_START         0x002
#define ARC_V2_LP_END           0x003
#define ARC_V2_STATUS32         0x00a
```

With all the values nicely aligned. Unfortunately clang-format does this;

```
#define ARC_V2_LP_START 0x002
#define ARC_V2_LP_END 0x003
#define ARC_V2_STATUS32 0x00a
```

I have found the AlignConsecutiveDeclarations and AlignConsecutiveAssignments options, but nothing that will align consecutive #defines. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: It appears that there is no such option. I'm currently working on adding it as a new style option, AlignConsecutiveMacros. You can see it here on my fork https://github.com/eriknyquist/clang/tree/align_defines

(I won't post a direct link to the commit, since I am continually amending it. Just view the list of commits and pick the latest one)

Comment: do you plan to submit a pull request? Looks like a useful addition to me!

Comment: @ErikNyquist Thanks for your pull request. Any idea why it's still stuck at review ?

Comment: (copy-pasting from another post where I just answered the same Q): There's just been a lot of churn, if you look over that link I posted to the review you'll see all the changes that have been requested (and that I have implemented). Then there was silence for a long, long time, and someone's just come back in the last month and essentially asked for the whole thing to be reworked, and I just don't have the time/energy anymore....

Comment: @ErikNyquist Thanks for the information. I've built clang-format with your patch and we've been using it for for months now, it's working well. Too bad for their lack of reactivity, it's obvious that many people want this feature...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**[UPDATE]**

The op's pull request finally went through and as of clang version 9.0.0 is live. The functionality is enabled by the `AlignConsecutiveMacros: true` option.

**[ORIGINAL]**

Weirdly enough this feature is yet to be implemented in clang; the formatting option for consecutive macros is currently missing.

Many developers are interested and there is a working pull request that has been waiting for approval for years: https://reviews.llvm.org/D28462?id=93341

You can integrate it or just wait whether they add it on the official branch, but at this point I doubt they will.

Comment: You may not have noticed, that the pull request was done by OP one year ago after he asked this question. Still, the question is unanswered, so it would be best for @ErikNyquist to accept one answer.

Comment: An update: It looks like the change has been accepted, and is ready to land! https://reviews.llvm.org/D28462?id=93341#1498067

Comment: and after ~2 years my patch was finally merged! at long last we have alignment for PP macros :) https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html

Answer (score 0):

At a quick glance over the [style options](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) it looks like there is currently no option for this. The only option which deals with preprocessing that I see is `IndentPPDirectives` which deals with indentations of `#if` blocks.

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't find any option for this either. Clang has trashed all of my defines that have been automatically aligned by emacs..

Comment: the latest clang-format supports aligning macros using `AlignConsecutiveMacros`

Comment: this is not working. i have enabled AlignConsecutiveMacros : true

Answer (score -1):

Note that clang-format-9 and above have an option of `AlignConsecutiveMacros: true` which can do the trick for you.

To install clang-format-9 on ubuntu/Debian you need to check `http://apt.llvm.org/`.

As an example, if you have Ubuntu 16.04/xenial, you need to do the following:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.llvm.org/xenial/ llvm-toolchain-xenial-9 main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/xenial/ llvm-toolchain-xenial-9 main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'
sudo apt update
sudo apt install clang-format-9
```

Possible to handle Trusty/Ubuntu 14.04 the same way.

Comment: oh, I meant `AlignConsecutiveMacros: true` .. Cut-pasted the wrong line from my clang-format config. I will edit the post.

Comment: Yes, I created a patch for that feature  "AlignConsecutiveMacros" myself when I found it didn't exist.